# Django-filter get all records when a specific value for a filter_field is passed

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, url-parameters, django-filter

I am using [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to filter my `Queryset`  on the basis of url params.

```
class WorklistViewSet(ModelViewSet):


    serializer_class = MySerializer
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()

    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, ]
    filterset_fields = ['class', ]
    # possible values of *class* which is allowed to be passed in the url params are ['first', 'second', 'ALL']. 

class MyModel(BaseModel):
       CLASS_CHOICES = (
        (FIRST_CLASS, 'first'),
        (SECOND_CLASS, 'second'),
    )
       class = models.CharField(choices=CLASS_CHOICES, max_length=3, )
```

URLs `http://127.0.0.1:8000?class=first` and `http://127.0.0.1:8000?class=first` are giving the expected results.

I want that when `http://127.0.0.1:8000?class=ALL` is called, **all the records** in my table should be listed i.e **without filtering**.

How can i do this while using `django-filter` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use Filter.method, as explained in the [docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#customize-filtering-with-filter-method).

In your case, I would do as follows:

```
class F(django_filters.FilterSet):
    klass = CharFilter(method='my_custom_filter')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['klass']

    def my_custom_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
        if value == 'ALL':
            return queryset
        return queryset.filter(**{
            name: value,
        })
```

Be also reminded that `class` is a reserved word in Python and cannot be used as a variable name. I've used `klass` instead, although that's used as something else in many Python books and may be confusing.